# Hash contains a key even though a key was not set

Tags: perl, hash, key

In my code I create a `hash` and then pass it to a function.

```
my %profile_hash = ();

getProfileInfo(\%profile_hash, $profile_path);
```

In the function, I do the following:

```
sub getProfileInfo{
    my %profile_hash = shift;
    my $profile_path = shift;

    foreach my $key (keys (%profile_hash)){
        print $key;
    }
}
```

I find that when I print the keys, I get:

`HASH(0x1b64448)`

Could anyone please tell me why this might be occurring? If I print the `keys` before I pass it to the function, it is empty as expected.

Comment: Always `use strict` and `use warnings`. You would have gotten this message if you'd been using them: "Reference found where even-sized list expected".

Comment: I have been using them. This is part of a `CGI` script and turns out this error was printed to the log which I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a scalar inside your sub to grab the passed hash ref, then defererence it in your loop:

```
sub getProfileInfo{
    my $profile_hash_ref = shift;
    my $profile_path = shift;

    foreach my $key (keys (%{ $profile_hash_ref })){
        print $key;
    }
}
```

[Pass by Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Pass-by-Reference)

Comment: Thank you toolic. Didn't know that this had to be dereferenced.